# Discord.py: How to use discord.Profile.connected_accounts

Tags: list, dictionary, tuples, discord.py, profile

I have been trying to get this to work for hours now, I want my discord bot to simply view and return what connected accounts a target account has (YouTube, Twitch, Spotify etc.), I have gotten it to output something but I can't do anything with it; need a solution.

```
import discord
from discord import Intents, Profile
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.bot(command_prefix = '!', intents = Intents.all())
token = 'abc123asdfghjkl;...'

@client.command()
async def hl(ctx, user: discord.Member = None):
    if user is None:
        user = ctx.author
    accounts = discord.user.Profile.connected_accounts
    print(accounts)

client.run(token)
```

Output: '<_collections._tuplegetter object at 0x000001C807BB9370>'

Here is the documentation for the library I'm working with:
https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Profile.connected_accounts

It says it returns a list of dicts but I don't know what to do with this tuplegetter object that it outputs, I would love for it to output something like this instead:

'[{"type": "twitch", "id": "92473777", "name": "discordapp"}]'

Answer (score 0):

You're referencing to the class itself there, not to an instance, the `user` argument is already a `discord.Member` object, you can then simply do:

```py
profile = await user.profile()
accounts = profile.connected_accounts
```

Also, bots cannot use this function

Comment: I ammended my code with yours and now it outputs nothing.

Comment: do you have `intents.members` enabled?

Comment: Yes. All intents are enabled.

Comment: Still outputs nothing. Does not even return any errors or anything.