# How to get the (GitHub) connection in Discord with discord.py?

Tags: python, github, discord, connection, bots

I want to make a bot which gets all GitHub contributors from a repo (already have a solution for this: PyGitHub) and gives all users on a discord server a role when they connected their discord to their github and contributed. How can I get this connection (from a User object in discord.py)?

Comment: i would recommend trying to find a way to see if a user's github is linked on their profile, then adding a role from there. [This](https://hypixel.net/threads/api-with-python-how-to-check-users-social-media-accounts.2814473/) forum will help you achieve this.

Comment: Well this gets Discord User Names from the Hypixel API and not some names from the discord API

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65220127/discord-py-how-to-use-discord-profile-connected-accounts) help? If that doesn't work I recommend just having a quick command word as host, like !verify [user].

Comment: No it doesn't help because this can't be used by bots

Comment: What do you mean by "quick command word"? How does the contributor (or not?) prove it's his account?

Comment: It isn't really an answer to your question, but I was saying a quick command word to give someone a role after you manually check if they're on github.